# Is the C# language version set per each solution configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

While working on a VS 2019 solution containing a project which targets .NET 4.5.2 and another project that targets .NET 4.8, I observed that if the Solution Configuration is set to anything other than "Debug" (this particular solution has "DEV", "FEATURE", "QA", "STG", and "PROD" configurations) I see in the VS Error List window errors indicating "Feature _______ is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater."

For reference, the errors are observed if a configuration other than "Debug" is selected here:

[image]

And then I receive these errors:

[image]

The project in question is set to use C# Language Level "Default (autodetect)":

[image]

I am likely not fully understanding how the language version relates to the different solution configurations, any why the "Debug" configuration appears to use the correct language version, and other conflagrations do not. Publishing the application using the various solution configurations does not yield any language version errors, however.

Comment: I've added an answer that I *hope* will help, but if it doesn't, it would be really helpful if you could provide a complete example of a project file (and ideally solution file as well, along with the C# file) that demonstrates the problem. In particular, at the moment we don't even know what kind of project it is - an "SDK-style" project or one of the older, more verbose ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language level is set in the project file. Project properties *can* be configuration-specific, or they can be general. (Note that "solution configuration" and "project configuration name" can be different as well, which is an added complication.)

You should look at the project file - I expect you'll find an MSBuild property of `LangVersion` that has a `Condition` attribute. Remove the `Condition` attribute to make that property apply for all configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  In my solution, the project that is targeting .NET 4.5.1 does have `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` within `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">`. For all other solution configurations, `<PropertyGroup>` does not have  `<LangVersion>`.  If I move  `<LangVersion>` to the `<PropertyGroup>` element without the "Condition" attribute, I no longer receive the errors.

Comment: @matt.f.c: Cracking. I'd strongly advise that if you can move any "old-style" projects to SDK-style projects, then do so. They're *so* much more readable, and very easily hand-editable. I try to avoid having *any* conditions unless I really, really need them :)